# Construção de projeto workflow

Tags: php, modelagem, workflow

Estou construindo um sistema  onde preciso registrar movimentações e exibir-las para determinados usuários assim como para o andamento do processo. Segue um exemplo:

```
Dep- Departamento.
Equipe- pertence ao departamento.
```

1. Dep1 - cadastra solicitação
2. Dep2 - Realiza solicitação

   - Equipe1 - executa solicitação(etapa1,etapa2,etapa3)

Em outro momento outra equipe recebe outra solicitação parercida mas executa mais etapas:

1. Dep1 - cadastra solicitação
2. Dep2 - Realiza solicitação

   - Equipe2 - executa solicitação(etapa1,etapa2...etapa5)

Já construí demanda,usuario, demanda_usuario, e fiquei na duvida de etapa e demanda_etapa. 
Estou na duvida como montar esse processo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você pode aplicar a seguinte modelagem:

```
//Cadastro dos departamentos
departamento
  - id (pk)
  - nome
  ...

//Cadastro das demandas, com o id do departamento que solicitou e o id que será preenchido com o id do departamento que irá executar.
demanda (solicitação)
  - id (pk)
  - dep_id_solicita (fk)
  - dep_id_realiza (fk)
  - descricao
  ...

//Etapas da demanda, com o id da demanda e chave extranjeria para a pessoa da equipe que a executará
demanda_etapa
  - id (pk)
  - demanda_id (fk)
  - equipe_id (fk) (equipe_pessoa)
  - pessoa_id (fk) (equipe_pessoa
  - numero

//Cadastro das pessoas, que fazem parte das equipes
pessoa (usuário)
  - id (pk)
  - nome
  ...

//Cadastro da equipe
equipe
  - id (pk)
  - apelido
  ...

//Cadastro das pessoas que fazem parte da equipe.
equipe_pessoa
  - equipe_id (fk)
  - pessoa_id (fk)
  - primary key(equipe_id, pessoa_id)
```

Comment: só não entendi bem demanda_etapa

Comment: Caro Thalles, a "demanda_etapa" é uma estrutura onde serão armazenadas as etapas executadas para atender à demanda. Podem ser etapas pré-definidas ou ela pode ser alimentada sob-demanda, depende muito do negócio.

Comment: Obrigado @Fábio na verdade tinha até construído mas não estava firme o pensamento nesse caminho, e agora com o esclarecimento vou deixar aberto e limitando etapas por equipes no frontend. No banco não posso limitar pq em uma demanda parecida pode ocorrer mais ou menos etapas. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento me ajudou bastante.